# Google API sends account email alert

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm developing an application that utilizes Google sign-in and the Gmail API. My test users, once logged in, keep receiving an email like the attached file.

Other applications with similar functionality (basic email access) do not seem to trigger these emails. Any ideas? It makes my app seem less trustworthy.

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code for sign in?

Comment: @abielita Pretty standard iOS google sign in flow with server-side access. :/

Comment: have you had your project validated by Google?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you are obtaining tokens with offline=true indicating a requirement to use the refresh token to renew expired access tokens. If you only require short-term access, perhaps you should remove the offline parameter in the construction of your auth request link.
In this scenario once the access token expires, then the scope will no longer be usable or renewable and so your end-users should not receive the alert emails.